# browser adding some number to url

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

I am trying to get xml through ajax like below in my javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
        url: 'https://santander.easycruit.com/intranet/intranett/export/xml/vacancy/list.xml',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'xml',
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (xml) {
            debugger;
            $(xml).find('Vacancy').each(function () {
                    $(this).find("Location").each(function () {
                        var name = $(this).text();
                        alert(name);
                    });
            });



        },
        statusCode: {
            404: function () {
                debugger;
                alert('Failed');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

but when i run code i get error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://santander.easycruit.com/intranet/intranett/export/xml/vacancy/list.xml?_=1460979186038. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mymachinename' is therefore not allowed access`

You can see there is some number appended to url like `_=1460979186038`

Is it because of this i am getting error.

Comment: This answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/36742124/4870935 is correct, however the error you are getting is because of CORS - check this out -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work

Answer (score 1):

The _=1460979186038 part is added by jquery ajax, as the mechanism to prevent cache. If I remember currectly that number is just a random + timestamp or something like that.

source: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

The reason you are getting the error is `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`, which means you are trying to send cross-domain messages but the server didn't allow it.

Comment: the url in my question actually will work on ur end as well as its public... can you tell how can i access this through ajax?

Comment: i have no control over that server

Comment: @happy sorry I didn't notice you put "crossDomain: true,", you do request cross domain but the server probably don't allow it in the response.

Comment: Maybe make something like proxy service on your localhost (where you store that javascript file), so you can call that website via curl and return the value.

Comment: @Mark can you give me examples on what are you trying to tell

Comment: @Happy I've added answer ilustrating how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's clearly that you are facing with the issue with cross domain request.
If you can control this server, you will need add the header in your server to allow cross domain or for testing purpose, you can use my add on in firefox to development and deal with CORS: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cross-domain-cors/?src=ss

Comment: OP mentioned that he doesn't have control.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments discussion I think you should make something like proxy server. Try this PHP code:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://santander.easycruit.com/intranet/intranett/export/xml/vacancy/list.xml");
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

It would simply fetch desired XML from passed URL and display it on the page.
Put the script on the same server your javascript is and call your server with ajax. This should eliminate CORS limitations.

Comment: For .NET I'd suggest using `System.Net.WebClient()`. The mechanism is the same: download the content and then display it.

Comment: Can you provide me example or code for it?  I am really struggling with this for long time now